# Set google chart width to 100% on page resize in angular 4+

Tags: html, css, angular, google-visualization

I have an app with many wrappers responsive to the site (A bunch of div's predefined from an API), those are filled with a google chart each. 
Issue is, when the page first loads the charts are rendered to the current size, and when window is resized only the wrappers change, not the charts itself.

How can I make something like this https://codepen.io/flopreynat/pen/BfLkA **without using Jquery** and would this need to be set in a particular life-cycle in Angular (e.g. onChange?) or just a function?

I am using a library that just retrieves data, so I don't have functions as this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  drawChart1();
  drawChart2();
});
```

Comment: Couldn't you just hook into the native javascript window resize event and then trigger the google charts redraw event?

Comment: That is really easy, didn't notice I had a function on the lib I'm using, trying and updating!

Comment: If you have a <google-chart> component you can simply use the [dynamicResize]="true" propery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you bind window:resize in Angular 4+:

```
import {ElementRef, HostListener, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {GoogleChartComponent} from 'ng2-google-charts';

...

export class YourChart {
  @ViewChild('chart') chart: GoogleChartComponent;
  ...
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onWindowResize(event: any) {
    let selection = this.chart.wrapper.visualization.getSelection();
    this.chart.redraw();
    this.chart.wrapper.visualization.setSelection(selection);
    // you can remove two lines that preserve selection if you don't need them
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution has worked for me (no Jquery required):

```
chartHeight = window.innerHeight * 0.35
chartWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.18
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    this.chartWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.18. //set an appropriate  factor
    this.chartHeight = window.innerHeight * 0.35
```

```html
<div (window:resize)="onResize($event)"></div>
.
.
<google-chart [width]="chartWidth" [height]="chartHeight" ... >
```